# Conditional pagebreak depending on counter

Tags: context

After hours and hours I am still not able to produce a simple `pagebreak`if a counter is tested successfully being equal to a constant in ConTeXt.

```
\definenumber[eintraege][way=bytext,prefix=no]
\setnumber[eintraege][1]

\definenumber[horst][way=bytext,prefix=no]
\setnumber[horst][3]

\starttext

\dorecurse{20}{
Einträge: \getnumber[eintraege]\hfill Horst: \getnumber[horst]\\

%\doif{\getnumber[eintraege]}{\getnumber[horst]}{\pagebreak}
%\doif{\getnumber[eintraege]}{horst}{\pagebreak}
%\doif{eintraege}{horst}{\pagebreak}
%\doif{\getnumber[eintraege]}{3}{\pagebreak}

\doif{\getnumber[eintraege]}{\getnumber[eintraege]}{\pagebreak}


\incrementnumber[eintraege]
}


\stoptext
```

All commented out versions do not produce a `pagebreak`while the trivial case that the counter is equal to itself does. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the the `\rawcountervalue` command to access the numeric value of the counter and not `\convertedcounter` (or the old name `\getnumber`) which prints the formatted representation of the counter.

```
\definecounter[eintraege][way=bytext,prefix=no]
\setcounter[eintraege][1]

\definecounter[horst][way=bytext,prefix=no]
\setcounter[horst][3]

\starttext

\dorecurse{20}
  {Einträge: \convertedcounter[eintraege]\hfill Horst: \convertedcounter[horst]\par
  %\ifnum\rawcountervalue[eintraege]=\rawcountervalue[horst]\relax\page\fi
   \doif{\rawcountervalue[eintraege]}{\rawcountervalue[horst]}{\page}%
   \incrementcounter[eintraege]}

\stoptext
```

The following example demonstrates the difference between the `\rawcountervalue` and `\convertedcounter` commands. When you use the `\convertedcounter` command ConTeXt applies the conversion for each level of the counter in the output and does also show the prefix for the number when you have enabled it. The `\rawcountervalue` command on the other side shows only the numeric value of the requested counter level and you can use it with TeX’s number commands like `\ifnum`.

```
\defineconversionset[testcounter][n,a,r][n]

\definecounter
  [testcounter]
  [prefix=yes,
   prefixsegments=section,
   numberconversionset=testcounter,
   prefixconnector=–]

\starttext

\section{Section 1}

\incrementcounter[testcounter]
\incrementcounter[testcounter][2]
\incrementcounter[testcounter][2]
\incrementcounter[testcounter][3]

\starttabulate[|l|l|l|]
\NC \bf Level \NC \bf Converted counter                              \NC \bf Raw counter                     \NC\NR
\NC 1         \NC \convertedcounter[testcounter][numbersegments=1:1] \NC \rawcountervalue   [testcounter]    \NC\NR
\NC 2         \NC \convertedcounter[testcounter][numbersegments=1:2] \NC \rawsubcountervalue[testcounter][2] \NC\NR
\NC 3         \NC \convertedcounter[testcounter][numbersegments=1:3] \NC \rawsubcountervalue[testcounter][3] \NC\NR
\stoptabulate

\section{Section 2}

\incrementcounter[testcounter]

\incrementcounter[testcounter][2]
\incrementcounter[testcounter][3]
\incrementcounter[testcounter][3]

\starttabulate[|l|l|l|]
\NC \bf Level \NC \bf Converted counter                              \NC \bf Raw counter                     \NC\NR
\NC 1         \NC \convertedcounter[testcounter][numbersegments=1:1] \NC \rawcountervalue   [testcounter]    \NC\NR
\NC 2         \NC \convertedcounter[testcounter][numbersegments=1:2] \NC \rawsubcountervalue[testcounter][2] \NC\NR
\NC 3         \NC \convertedcounter[testcounter][numbersegments=1:3] \NC \rawsubcountervalue[testcounter][3] \NC\NR
\stoptabulate

\stoptext
```

[image: Differences between converted and raw counter representation]

Comment: Thank you @Metafox. Again hours and hours wasted by insufficient documentation. Could you explain what the difference between a formatted value and an unformatted value here is?

Comment: Great answer! Some of this should be added the the wiki   page on counters, which is very terse